# Ember.js "hasMany through"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Does Ember Data have an analogue to Rails' `has_many ..., :through =>` functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not. There is an open issue for this to be added in the `1.0 Beta` milestone: [Many to Many Associations](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/120)

See Andre's answer [Ember-data polymorphic associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452361/ember-data-polymorphic-associations) for a look at how we are working around this for now.